# Excel - auto increment of multyple cells after each print

Tags: excel, vba, cell, increment

I need to increment numbers in green cells (see added picture) lineary after every print. for example if i set starting number in first table (green cell, C2) to be 1, following cells K2,C21,K21 will be printed as 2,3,4 and after that they will rise up accordingly to 5,6,7,8 in next printed copy unless destinated number of printed copies is reached.

here is example of my sheet

[image: Example sheet]

i tried to look up macro for this but found only one working in the way i desire.

```
Sub PrintCopies_ActiveSheet()
    
Dim CopiesCount As Long
Dim copynumber As Long
    
CopiesCount = Application.InputBox("How many copies do you want?", Type:=1)
    
For copynumber = 1 To CopiesCount
With ActiveSheet
       .Range("C2,K2,C21,K21").Value = copynumber 
       .PrintOut 'Print the sheet
    
End With
    Next copynumber
    End Sub
```

Sadly its adapted only for 1 cell, so when i print this sheet. All focused cells have same number (first print = 1,1,1,1; second print = 2,2,2,2 and so on.

Thank you excel gods in advance and have a nice day.
With best regards,
Morty

Comment: @xShen `For i` loops automatically iterate by 1 as default - if you wanted to change the increment further you would use `Step`. I don't think that is what OP needs. It's actually not clear what OP needs and he complicated it even more by asking multiple questions. Morty, note that stack overflow is 1 question:1 answer. You should [edit] your question to focus on a single issue. If you have multiple issues, then you will likely need multiple questions unless they are are directly related to same problem from a debugging viewpoint. Voting to close as this question needs clarity and focus

Comment: Hi guys, I am sorry, I have asked in rush. E1 is not relevant. I have just copied example code which i tried to apply in this case. The green cells are cells in which i would like to change numbers after every print. To focus on and simplify my first question. I just need to change numbers in green cells lineary after every print. for example if i set starting number in first table (green cell, C2)  to be 1, following cells K2,C21,K21 will be printed as 2,3,4 and after that they will rise up accordingly to 5,6,7,8 in next printed copy unless destinated number of printed copies is reached.

Comment: `range("c2").value=range("c2").value+1` ?

Comment: Hi, yeah but just from look it only solves the increment in first cell, I need the other 3 values (K2,C21,K21) to rise acordingly and lineary to first cell (C2). Its just numbering of documents in work. I will probably need loop for this one.

Answer (score 0):

So I have luckily found old thread with this amazing macro and adjusted it for my needs. It is working magicaly: D. One last question, is there posibility to use number in cell C1 as start number instead copynumber to set up starting point? Maybe even option to set up taskbar asking for starting number. Its for my collegues so I am trying to make it as easy as posible

**macro:**

```
Public Sub IncrementPrint()
    Dim resp As Variant, scr As Boolean, i As Long, j As Long

On Error Resume Next
    resp = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the number of copies to print:", _
                                Title:="Select Total Print Copies", Type:=1)
On Error GoTo 0

    If resp = False Then Exit Sub
    If resp < 1 Or resp > 100 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid number: " & resp & " (Enter 1 to 100)", vbExclamation, "Try Again"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    scr = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    j = 0
    For i = 1 To resp
        ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Value2 = i + 0 + j
        ActiveSheet.Range("K2").Value2 = i + 1 + j
        ActiveSheet.Range("C21").Value2 = i + 2 + j
        ActiveSheet.Range("K21").Value2 = i + 3 + j
        ActiveSheet.PrintOut
        j = j + 3
    Next i
    ActiveSheet.Range("C2,K2,C21,K21").ClearContents
    Application.ScreenUpdating = scr
End Sub
```

EDIT:
Hm I have solved it myself, just if someone could take a look on my code and confirm its writen good to avoid posible future bugs :D

```
Public Sub IncrementPrint()
    Dim resp As Variant, scr As Boolean, i As Long, j As Long

On Error Resume Next
    resp = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the number of copies to print:", _
                                Title:="Select Total Print Copies", Type:=1)
On Error GoTo 0

    If resp = False Then Exit Sub
    If resp < 1 Or resp > 100 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid number: " & resp & " (Enter 1 to 100)", vbExclamation, "Try Again"
        Exit Sub
    End If


On Error Resume Next
    StartValue = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter start number:", _
                                Title:="Start number", Type:=1)
On Error GoTo 0

    If StartValue = False Then Exit Sub
    If StartValue < 1 Or resp > 10000 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid number: " & StartValue & " (Enter 1 to 10000)", vbExclamation, "Try Again"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    scr = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    j = 0
    For i = 1 To resp
        ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Value2 = i + 0 + j + StartValue - 1
        ActiveSheet.Range("K2").Value2 = i + 1 + j + StartValue - 1
        ActiveSheet.Range("C21").Value2 = i + 2 + j + StartValue - 1
        ActiveSheet.Range("K21").Value2 = i + 3 + j + StartValue - 1
        ActiveSheet.PrintOut
        j = j + 3
    Next i
    ActiveSheet.Range("C2,K2,C21,K21").ClearContents
    Application.ScreenUpdating = scr
End Sub
```